# What's the meaning of "cross any of our desks"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

So I saw this line from a TV drama (again) and couldn't understand it. Here is the line:

> But Michaela Stone remains a person of interest in the most perplexing investigation ever to **cross any of our desks**.

What's the meaning of "cross any of our desks"? I was guessing "according to our records" or something like that.

Comment: We typically add examples and quotations in a "blockquote" using the `>` character. See the [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) for more tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's a variation on the idiom

["To cross one's path"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cross+your+path)

Which means "to encounter". The author substituted the word "desks" for "path" to emphasise the idea that the encounter happened at work.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase to "cross my desk" or "come across my desk" is an idiom meaning **to be introduced to**/**to see** (usually in a working context).

In this context then, the sentence means "Michaela Stone remains a person of interest in the most perplexing investigation **we have ever seen at work.**" (Emphasis mine).